# Installing Myst (game) on a 64-bit Operating System

Tags: windows-vista

I'm trying to install my MYST game on a 64bit operation and I can't because I need a 32bit operation. I get a message:

> "The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check you computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, then contact the software publisher."

I have a 64 bit Win Vista PC - How can I install my favorite game?

Comment: Have you tried compatibility mode? Other than that, there might not be a solution other than having a 32-bit system.

Comment: The problem is Mist is using 16 bit and the 64 bit version of windows does not support 16 bit.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look: http://www.gog.com/forum/myst_series/myst_masterpiece_edition_problems_on_windows_7_64_bit/page1

The compability mode (like Doktoro Reichard wrote above) is necessary!

> Hello everyone!!! I'm not sure if anyone is still having this problem,
>   but I found a solution!!!
>
> I pulled my old myst disks out of a box and decided to install them
>   and see if I could once again finish them. And of course I was having
>   the same problem posted here!!!
>
> This is what I did:
>
> 1. Uninstall Myst or Myst ME - whichever you have
> 2. Uninstall QuickTime - I used 'ControlPanel>Programs and Features' to do both of these
> 3. Go to 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64'
> 4. Scroll down and find "QuickTime.qts" and delete it - (Yes, Delete it!!!)
> 5. Restart your machine
> 6. Install your copy of Myst w/QuickTime provided on the disk
> 7. DO NOT update QuickTime when asked - just finish the install
> 8. Go back to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" and find the "QuickTime.qts" file again
> 9. Right-click and copy this file
> 10. Go to your Myst folder - usually "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubi Soft\Myst Masterpiece Edition (this was the situation in my case for
>       Myst ME)
> 11. Paste the copied "QuickTime.qts" file in this directory
> 12. Restart your machine and run the game in Compatability Mode for Windows 98
>
> Enjoy and I hope this helps the rest of those Myst fanatics in the
>   world!!!!!